# Determining which script started a process from the process description

Tags: process

I have the following process:

```
  oracle8  602592       1   0   Nov 14      -  2:54 ora_mmon_RRT
```

How I can find the name and full path of the script that activated the process?

Comment: why I dont get answer , its seems easy question -:(